# TypeError: t is not a function at Dr

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I am getting this error

TypeError: t is not a function at Dr (http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:73052) at Or (http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:73238) at xl (http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:92482) at http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:89829 at v (http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:3385) at ce (http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:5527) at A. (http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.min.js?ver=3.15.0:1:16077) at P (http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.min.js?ver=3.15.0:1:15885) at MessagePort.E (http://blue-crab-crossfit-gw.local/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.min.js?ver=3.15.0:1:15942)

After updating the wordpress version to 6.2.2, All is working fine under 6.1.3

Using Wordpress react setup @wordpress/scripts